# Average of frequency table-apply function

Tags: r, algorithm

If we want to calculate the average of frequency for event in the first data set , We can use the below function.

```
ID<-c("R1","R2","R2","R3","R3","R4","R4","R4","R4","R3","R3","R3","R3","R2","R2","R2","R5","R6")
event<-c("a","b","b","M","s","f","y","b","a","a","a","a","s","c","c","b","m","a")
df<-data.frame(ID,event)
```

function:

```
apply(table(df$ID,df$event),2,function(x) mean(x[x>0]))
```

I was wondering how I can modify this code to calculate the average of frequency for event by considering the levels of type. I mean, I want to calculate `apply(table(df$ID,df$event),2,function(x) mean(x[x>0]))` for each level of type. Forexample in aaa level, the average of frequency for a is 2/2. In cc level, the average of frequency for b= 3/1.

```
ID<-   c("R1","R2","R2","R3","R3","R4","R4","R4","R4","R3","R3","R3","R3","R2","R2","R2","R5","R6")
 event<-c("a","b","b","M","s","f","y","b","a","a","a","a","s","c","c","b","m","a")
 type<-c("ee","cc","cc","mm","mm","ff","yy","bb","cc","mm","ff","aaa","cc","ccc","ff","cc","mmm","aaa")

df<-data.frame(ID,event,type)
```

Comment: Do you just want the frequency of the items in vectors. Then use `prop.table`. The phrase "average of frequency for event" is somewhat confusing. It could mean many things. Perhaps you just need to exclude the first column named "ID"  if you want the analogous result for 'type'.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to have the average for the unique combinations of ID and type. Then this is what you want:

```
table <- unlist(apply(table(df), 2, function(x) x))
apply(table, 2, function(x) mean(x[x>0]))
```

Thomas

---

Comment: thanks so much for your reply. What I need is to calculate the average of frequency for event= sum(event)/number of ID, by considering the levels of type. I mean, I want to calculate apply(table(df$ID,df$event),2,function(x) mean(x[x>0])) for each level of type.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the "average count" in the columns of of a 2way table with "event" as the outcome, you need to exclude the ID column and then use apply along rows rather than columns:

```
> table(df[-1])
     type
event aaa bb cc ccc ee ff mm mmm yy
    a   2  0  1   0  1  1  1   0  0
    b   0  1  3   0  0  0  0   0  0
    c   0  0  0   1  0  1  0   0  0
    f   0  0  0   0  0  1  0   0  0
    m   0  0  0   0  0  0  0   1  0
    M   0  0  0   0  0  0  1   0  0
    s   0  0  1   0  0  0  1   0  0
    y   0  0  0   0  0  0  0   0  1

> apply(table(df[-1]),1,function(x) mean(x[x>0]))
  a   b   c   f   m   M   s   y 
1.2 2.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

If you really want what is described in then use and index of `3`:

```
> apply(table(df),3,function(x) mean(x[x>0]))
     aaa       bb       cc      ccc       ee       ff       mm      mmm       yy 
1.000000 1.000000 1.666667 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
```

(I'm not sure how this procedure leads to useful results.)

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I want to calculate apply(table(df$ID,df$event),2,function(x) mean(x[x>0])) for each level of type.

Comment: Thanks, but what I want is something like this: the average of frequency for b in cc level is 3/1=3. Since  sum(frequency(b))=3 and number of ID is 1 (R2) and etc.